# Python return if statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement, syntax

Unclear on how to frame the following function correctly:

Creating a function that will take in a string and return the string in camel case without spaces (or pascal case if the first letter was already capital), removing special characters

```py
text = "This-is_my_test_string,to-capitalize"

def to_camel_case(text):
    # Return 1st letter of text + all letters after
    return text[:1] + text.title()[1:].replace(i" ") if not i.isdigit()

# Output should be "ThisIsMyTestStringToCapitalize"
```

the "if" statement at the end isn't working out, and I wrote this somewhat experimentally, but with a syntax fix, could the logic work?

Comment: `i` is not defined.

Comment: Also `else` part is missing.

Comment: Should it not return if `i` is all digits? What does that even mean?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get something you weren't expecting? Do you get an error?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement.

Comment: Where's the `if` statement you talked about?

Comment: In order to resolve the discussions around the strict definition of camel case, please show your expected output. Do you want lower camel case or PascalCase (a.k.a. upper camel case)

Answer (score 0):

Providing the input string does not contain any spaces then you could do this:

```
from re import sub
def to_camel_case(text, pascal=False):
    r = sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', text).title().replace(' ', '')
    return r if pascal else r[0].lower() + r[1:]
ts = 'This-is_my_test_string,to-capitalize'
print(to_camel_case(ts, pascal=True))
print(to_camel_case(ts))
```

**Output:**

```
ThisIsMyTestStringToCapitalize
thisIsMyTestStringToCapitalize
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution using regex. First it uses title() as you did, then the regex finds non-alphanumeric-characters and removes them, and finally we take the first character to handle pascal / camel case.

```
import re

def to_camel_case(s):
    s1 = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', s.title())
    return s[0] + s1[1:]

text = "this-is2_my_test_string,to-capitalize"
print(to_camel_case(text)) # ThisIsMyTestStringToCapitalize
```

Answer (score -1):

The below should work for your example.

Splitting apart your example by anything that isn's alphanumeric or a space. Then capitalizing each word. Finally, returning the re-joined string.

```py
import re


def to_camel_case(text):
    words = re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', text)
    return "".join([word.capitalize() for word in words])

text_to_camelcase = "This-is_my_test_string,to-capitalize"
print(to_camel_case(text_to_camelcase))
```

Answer (score -1):

use the split function to split between anything that is not a letter or a whitespace and the function .capitalize() to capitalize single words

```
import re
text_to_camelcase = "This-is_my_test_string,to-capitalize"

def to_camel_case(text):
    split_text = re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', text)

    cap_string = ''
    for word in split_text:
        cap_word = word.capitalize()
        cap_string += cap_word

    return cap_string


print(to_camel_case(text_to_camelcase))
```